# Run preprocessor and keep directives

Tags: gcc

Is there a way I can run `gcc -E` to run the preprocessor but also to *keep* the `#define`, `#include`, other directives in the output (possibly as comments)?  I thought I remembered seeing an option for this but I can't find it in the GCC Preprocessor Options page.  I need this to track down where things are going wrong in a complex case involving lots of include files and macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant options are listed under `-dCHARS`. `-dD` outputs macro definitions (both `#define` and `#undef` directives), `-dI` outputs `#include` directives, and they can be combined to `-dDI`.